# Sqlalchemy + Postgres: synthetic/artificial id mixin with sequence

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, sequence, mixins, synthetic

I've found the mixin pattern to be really handy for staying DRY, but I am having trouble with sequences.  Note, I'm using postgres.

We use alembic migrations, and I'd really like the `--autogeneration` to work with this sequence, though I understand [this might not be possible right now](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/issues/73).  However, it looks like setting up the sequence without an ORM identifier, prevents the sequence from being dropped later if I wanted to perform a downgrade.

Through googling, I found [some explanation on how to properly setup a sequence](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/01foLdWlwLY/S7uo9oFuBAAJ).  Essentially: separate the id and its sequence.

Current Code looks a bit like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

class AutoIdMixin(object):
    """Generates an synthetic identifier primary key.
    """

    # See: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#associating-a-sequence-as-the-server-side-default
    @declared_attr
    def id_seq(cls):
        bases = cls.__bases__
        Base = bases[0]
        sequence_prefix = 'seq'
        schema = cls._schema_name
        sequence_id = '_'.join((sequence_prefix, schema, cls.__tablename__, 'id'))
        sequence = sa.Sequence(sequence_id, 1, 1, metadata=Base.metadata)
        return sequence

    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        column_id = sa.Column(sa.types.Integer, cls.id_seq.next_value(), primary_key=True)
        return column_id
```

With the code above, I end up with a non-helpful error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'next_value' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'
```

Answer (score 0):

In an RTM moment, it looks like I missed a keyword: [server_default](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#associating-a-sequence-as-the-server-side-default).

```
    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        sequence = cls.id_seq
        column_id = sa.Column(sa.types.Integer, server_default=sequence.next_value(), primary_key=True)
        return column_id
```